# Swift: Singleton class "extends" from protocol

Tags: swift, syntax-error, singleton, protocols

I'm trying to make a singleton class from a protocol, my intentions with this is to have multiple xxxxxHandlers, eg. SpotifyHandler, AppleMusicHandler and so on... and create the correct one when a user logs in with their music-account, then make the handler accessible all throughout the program.

But when i try to make SpotifyHandler i run into this error:
`Property 'shared' in non-final class 'SpotifyHandler' must specify type 'Self' to conform to protocol 'MusicHandler'`

On this line: `static var shared: SpotifyHandler = SpotifyHandler()`

Here's the code for the singleton class and protocol (separate files)

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class SpotifyHandler : MusicHandler {
    static var shared: SpotifyHandler = SpotifyHandler()
    
    var is_logged_in: Bool = false;
 
    func set_is_logged_in(is_logged_in: Bool) {
        self.is_logged_in = is_logged_in
    }
    
    func print_status() {
        print("--- Status ---")
        print("Is logged in: \(self.is_logged_in)")
    }
}


public protocol MusicHandler {
    static var shared: Self { get }
    
    var is_logged_in: Bool { get }
    
    func set_is_logged_in(is_logged_in: Bool)
    func print_status()
}
```

I am quite new to swift but have experience in other languages, i am open to suggestions on alternative ways to solve this if you have any. :)

Comment: Edited it to text instead of screenshots.

Comment: A simple solution is to declare the class as `final`. It's not so common to inherit from a singleton anyway. Then one also can ask why it is necessary for the protocol that any conforming type has a `shared` property. Maybe one day you want to use the object as an @Environment object rather than a singleton

Comment: Thanks, I will use *final* for now, although I'm quite curious how this would be solved otherwise, I didn't manage to find any information on singleton classes "extending" protocols in swift.

Comment: You can add an associated type and then let shared be of this type in the protocol. Then you won't have to use `final`

Comment: Unrelated, but [don't write getters and setters in Swift](https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Stop%20writing%20getters%20and%20setters%20in%20Swift.md)

Comment: Thanks Alexander, really useful information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because `SpotifyHandler` being a class can have subclasses. If you create a sub class that inherits from `SpotifyHandler` it will not conform to the protocol because `Self` has got to simultaneously have type `SpotifyHandler` and the type of the subclass e.g.

```
class AdFreeSpotifyHandler: SpotifyHandler {}

let foo = AdFreeSpotifyHandler.shared
```

What type would you expect `foo` to have?

There are two solution: you can do what @lorum ipsum suggests and make the shared instance of type `MusicHandler` or you can stop people from subclassing `SpotifyHandler` by making it `final` i.e.

```
final class SpotifyHandler : MusicHandler {
    static var shared: SpotifyHandler = SpotifyHandler() // No error
    // rest of the implementation
}
```

As a general rule, as soon as your protocol has any `Self` requirements or an associated type, you can't make non final classes conform to it.

---

I don't recommend @lorum ipsum's approach on the whole because if I have

```
class AdFreeSpotifyHandler: SpotifyHandler
{
}

let foo = AdFreeSpotifyHandler.shared
```

We know `foo` is a `MusicHandler`, but it's not an `AdFreeSpotifyHandler` which is what you'd really want in the above fragment.